# uninitialized constant CustomersController - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having trouble with my routing in a Rails app. I get this error when I try to follow a link to the new_customer_path:

```
uninitialized constant CustomersController
```

This is the link I am trying to follow. It is on the "new" page for my Movies controller. Here is the relevant portion of the "new" page:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <hr />
    <%= link_to "Add Customer", new_customer_path, class: 'white' %>
</div>
</div>
```

Customer Controller:

```
class CustomerController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @customer = Customer.new 
  end

  def create
    @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
    if @customer.save 
      redirect_to new_customer_path
    end 
  end

  private 

   def customer_params
    params.require(:customer).permit(:fname, :lname, :telephone, :email)
   end

end
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :customers

  resources :movies do 
    resources :rentals
  end 
  root 'movies#new'
end
```

Customer Model:

```
 class Customer < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :rentals 
 end
```

Any thoughts/tips would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be that you're missing an `s`?

`class CustomerController < ApplicationController` should be `class CustomersController < ApplicationController`

Rails is convention over configuration which means:

- Models are singular: `Object`
- Controllers are plural: `ObjectsController`

This can be changed if you would like, but I would stick with convention unless you have a good reason.

Comment: That's a good catch! Unfortunately, it didn't fix the wider issue. Now I get this instead "uninitialized constant CustomersController"

Comment: Did you rename the controller, but not the file it resides in?

Comment: That was the issue. Thank you both!